# confusing sizeof operator result

Tags: c++, sizeof

I'm a bit confused about a sizeof result.

I have this :

```
unsigned  long part1 = 0x0200000001;
cout << sizeof(part1); // this gives 8 byte
```

if I count correctly, part 1 is 9 byte long right ?

Can anybody clarify this for me

thanks
Regards

Comment: How did you conclude that `part1` is 9 bytes long?

Comment: to hold that value, it would only need to be 5 bytes large

Comment: unsigned longs are 8 bytes long in your system.

Comment: `0x0200000001` is not 9 bytes long

Comment: Is it `part1` or `part`?

Comment: sorry it's part1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I count correctly, part 1 is 9 byte long right ?

No, you are counting incorrectly. `0x0200000001` can fit into five bytes. One byte is represented by two hex digits. Hence, the bytes are `02 00 00 00 01`.

Comment: You'd still need to store that number in a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you misinterpret the meaning of `sizeof`. `sizeof(type)` returns the number of bytes that the system reserves to hold *any value of the respective type*. So `sizeof(int)` on an 32 bit system will probably give you `4` bytes, and `8` bytes on a 64 bit system, `sizeof(char[20])` gives `20`, and so on.
Note that one can use also identifiers of (typed) variables, e.g. `int x; sizeof(x)`; `type` is then deduced from the variable declaration/definition, such that `sizeof(x)` is the same as `sizeof(int)` in this case.

But: `sizeof` never ever interprets or analyses the content / the value of a variable at runtime, even if `sizeof` somehow sounds as if. So `char *x = "Hello, world"; sizeof(x)` is *not* the string length of string literal `"Hello, world"` but the size of type `char*`.

So your `sizeof(part1)` is the same as `sizeof(long)`, which is `8` on your system regardless of what the actual content of `part1` is at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you explanation, I can see clearly now why I was confused.

Answer (score 0):

An `unsigned long` has a minimum range of `0 to 4294967295` that's `4 bytes`.

Assigning `0x0200000001 (8589934593)` to an `unsigned long` that's not big enough will trigger a conversion so that it fits in an `unsigned long` on your machine. This conversion is implementation-defined but usually the higher bits will be discarded.

`sizeof` will tell you the amount of bytes a type uses. It won't tell you how many bytes are occupied by your value.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(part1)`   (I'm assuming you have a typo) gives the size of a `unsigned long`   (i.e. `sizeof(unsigned long)`).    The size of `part1` is therefore the same regardless of what value is stored in it.

On your compiler, `sizeof(unsigned long)` has value of `8`.   The size of types is implementation defined for all types (other than `char` types that are defined to have a size of `1`), so may vary between compilers.

The value of `9` you are expecting is the size of output you will obtain by writing the value of `part1` to a file or string as human-readable hex, with no leading zeros or prefix.   That has no relationship to the `sizeof` operator whatsoever.   And, when outputting a value, it is possible to format it in different ways (e.g. hex versus decimal versus octal,  leading zeros or not) which affect the size of output

Answer (score -1):

`sizeof(part1)`  returns the size of the data type of variable `part1`, which you have defined as `unsigned long`.

The bit-size of `unsigned long` for your compiler is always 64 bits, or 8 bytes long, that's 8 groups of 8 bits.  The hexadecimal representation is a human readable form of the binary format, where each *digit* is 4 bits long.  **We humans often omit leading zeroes for clarity, computers never do.**

Let's consider a single byte of data - a `char` - and the value zero.

```
 - decimal:         0
 - hexadecimal :   0x0   (often written as 0x00)
 - binary:         0000 0000
```

For a list of C++ data types and their corresponding bit-size check out the documentation at (the msvc documentation is easier to read):

for msvc:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.71).aspx

for gcc: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Data-Types

All compilers have documentation for their data sizes, since they depend on the hardware *and* the compiler itself.  If you use a different compiler, a google search on "'your compiler name' data sizes" will help you find the correct sizes for your compiler.

Comment: _"he bit-size of unsigned long for your compiler is always 64 bits"_ - No it's not. Please refer to the C++ Standard instead of implementation specific notes.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious He does say *your compiler* so kinda works but I agree with you.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah but the OP didn't specify a compiler in their post and there's no followup in the comments. Score one for me for being a pedantic douche :)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Since OP stated:`cout << sizeof(part); // this gives 8 byte`  we can assume safely that `unsigned long` is indeed 64-bits long on his compiler, can't we?

Comment: We can be pretty sure of 8 bytes. 7-bit bytes went out of style, so 64 bits is a safe guess.